# Spring Security - BcryptPasswordEncoder

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I use Spring security in our Application and would like to validate user input with the password stored in the DB for the change password option.

The password is stored as follows in DB.

```
user.setPassword(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode("<userPassword>"));
```

Here the user entered password is encoded using the above logic and stored in the DB. Now I am just trying to get password from user for change password. After getting the password from user I encode using the above logic and try to compare with the DB. The encoded value seems to be different even I use the same logic for encoding.

My configuration from `WebSecurityConfig`:

```
@Autowired
public void configAuthentication(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());

}
```

I am not sure what is wrong with comparison.

Comment: How did you compare the encoded passwords with each other? Using `String#equals` or `PasswordEncoder#matches`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The encoded value seems to be different even I use the same logic for
>   encoding.

Bcrypt algorithm uses a built-in salt value which is different each time. So, yes even for the same *Clear Text* same encoding process would generate different *Cipher Text*s.

> After getting the password from user I encode using the above logic
>   and try to compare with the DB

Do not encode the *Raw Password*. Suppose `rawPassword` is the password that client gave you and `encodedPassword` is the encoded stored password in the database. Then, instead of encoding the `rawPassword` and comparing the result using `String#equals`, use the `PasswordEncoder#matches` method:

```
PasswordEncoder passwordEnocder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
if (passwordEncoder.matches(rawPassword, encodedPassword)) {
    System.out.println("Matched!");
}
```