# Retype current password in password change using BCryptPasswordEncoder Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have an application that has a feature that changes the password.

I use a `BCryptPasswordEncoder` to encode the password and add to the database, Spring Security can handle this with this code:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authentication) throws Exception {
    authentication
                  .jdbcAuthentication()
                      .dataSource(dataSource)
                      .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
}
```

I am trying to implement it into a Controller that the user must type the current password. The `BCryptPasswordEncoder` is called and it encrypts the password but it does not match to the password stored in DB.

Any idea to solve this?

Comment: How did you compare those cipher texts? If you're comparing them through `String#equals`, then see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36324113/spring-security-bcryptpasswordencoder/36328015#36328015

Comment: @AliDehghani Thank you, it worked, a little modification but worked. I will post the answer!

Comment: Glad it worked but...It would be better if we close this question as duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

With the help of the comments section I got the answer.

I am now comparing the `rawPassword` with the `encodedPassword` using the `matches()` function coming from `BCryptPasswordEncoder`.

What I did was:

```
final BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

    if(passwordEncoder.matches(rawPassword, encodedPassword)){
        return true;
    else{
       return false;
       }
```